# Cant put a number into 2d array idk why

Tags: c++, arrays

ok so im trying to print all characters in a computer.
I did a nested loop to put all numbers into the 2d array and print them.

```
   int count = 0;
 char counte[4][5] = {{' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                       {' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                       {' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                       {' ',' ',' ',' ',' '}};


 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    { 
        count++;
        char thing =static_cast<char>(count);
      counte[i][j] = thing;
        
      
    }
    
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  
    cout << "\n";
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
       cout  << counte[i][j];
    }
    
}
```

The problem is, when i try to print them it shows whitespaces!!!111!
pls help i think the bug is in the first nested loop  :c.

Comment: also im new so dont expect good code

Comment: you can store single digits in the array, but it is not clear what you want to happen when `count` is `>=10`. Please include expected output in the quesiton

Comment: btw we don't expect "good" code but we expect a [mcve], code that others can compile, and expected output should also be part of the problem description.

Comment: What characters _do_ you expect to be printed? If your goal is to print all possible characters, what would you expect the first 20 which you are printing to look like? Hint: look at a ASCII table and read up on what these characters do

Comment: You can start [with this](https://godbolt.org/z/x6zshx9oE). I don't see the need to use an `int` if you want a `char`. Forget the cast and use a `char` directly. Also, no need of nested loops to print characters (even inside an array). Then, if the goal is just to print them, I don't see why the bother of storing them into an array :) And so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters you are trying to print aren't visible characters. You can check what visible ones (starting from 33) at [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: thx bro how did u know that?